# Suitable symbols for "the beginning/end of"?

Tags: symbols

I would like some suggestions for suitable symbols or graphical elements for *the beginning/end of* something (a road or something more metaphysical).

I will match them with existing elements indicating *ahead of/to the rear of, beyond/in front of, above/under* and so on. For these I used a 3D image of a car and located the different labels on suitable locations.

Comment: I don't know what your app does but why not just the words "Start" and "End", why make the user guess a symbols' meaning?

Comment: Hard. I can't imagine a symbol the beginning of something metaphysical. Maybe at the graphics stackexchange site? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/  Or wait - teaser: not serious - a car with full and empty gas tank? Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "First Page" and "Last Page" icons are what you are looking for.

---

[Example (Material Design Icons)](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=first_page&style=baseline)

*CTRL+F for "first_page" and "last_page".*

Answer (score 1):

What about the old icons for fast-forwarding or rewinding, these could be adapted. However, it depends on your context of use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to source your answer from the domain you are designing for. 
For driving those are the end of road icons, for music everyone knows them so try to determine if your work is addressing a specific domain. If not try to use universal symbols.

[image]

Comment: I am actually making a kind of cloze test for language learning and want to include as many "senses" as possible, not just translate a word from one language to another.